# Android Trigger action on another device

Tags: android, networking

I want to send simple data between two phones. For example: When I press a button on device A on device B an action gets executed, for example, a sound gets played. How can I do this? Which methods would work well?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: there are multiple ways to aproach this, is depends how the phone a and B are connectable...
Q: are both in the same network?
Q: are both paired by, for example Bluetooth?
what do you have in mind??

Comment: I think the internet is the best way to connect the devices because most devices have permanently internet connection also i can reach the other device from anywhere in the world. I know that it will be much more easier when both devices in the same network are so that is also a possibility for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need a notification service, and google has something like that for us...

[image]

## How does this works??

Take a look at  the image posted over,

you need to register your android app in the google service, and your web interface will need an id, so every time you want to push something to the android, your web interface instead will push it to the google server with the Id of the app, then google (no matter how) will localize your app, and even if its not running, they will get the notification,

behind the scenes there is a couple of thing that you must do, bu nothing like launching rockets from the NASA.

I will suggest to take a look to some [tutorials](http://javapapers.com/android/android-device-to-device-messaging-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-via-http/)
in order to start with the registration of your app, get the API key etc etc..

Comment: That sound good, but i don't want to send a notification but i want to execute some code on the receiver phone.